# Type checking of infix operators in compiler

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction

I'm writing a compiler (in Haskell) and in the grammar of the language there are rules to add infix operators (addition is used as an example):

```
EAdd . Expr ::= Expr "+" Expr
```

which means `EAdd` is an expression, it's consist of expression, string `"+"` and another expression.

Parser returns abstract syntax tree (AST):

```
data Expr = ... | EAdd Expr Expr
```

I want to make a typechecker if checks that calls of the functions are given arguments of correct types.

Note, that "+" is a function that takes two integers and returns an integer. Other operators are similar.

At the moment I came up with three approaches to typechecking `EAdd`, all of them include adding "+" as a function to the initial symbol table:

1. Declare that infix plus is syntax sugar for calling function "+" with two arguments. Put "desugarizer" which converts AST from parser into *another* data type (without `EAdd`) in between parser and typechecker.
2. (similar to the first) Declare that infix plus is syntax sugar, but desugarizer uses same AST data type. Typechecker returns an error when it's given `EAdd`.
3. Inline "desugarizer" into typechecker. Similar to this:

   ```
   ...
   typecheck (EAdd a b) = typecheck (ECall infixPlus [a, b])
   ...
   ```

Note, that all binary infix operators are subject to this (other arithmetic, boolean operations, comparison operators).

It seems that first approach is the correct one. But it means that later in the compiler pipeline, particularly in the *code generator*,  those `ECalls` should be handled as special cases, because in the compilers output (in my case — llvm) these functions  are supposed to be inlined (unlike usual function calls).
It means that codegen has a list of functions whose calls are be handled differently from other function calls.

What is the best approach to this issue?

**UPD**

How this similar issue is handled in Haskell (from https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/Renamer):

> ... renamer does the following things:
>
> - Sort out fixities. The parser parses all infix applications as left-associative, regardless of fixity. For example "a + b * c" is parsed as "(a + b) * c". The renamer re-associates such nested operator applications, using the fixities declared in the module.

Comment: It's a nice and readable description of your current thinking. What's the question you want answered?

Comment: It seems to me that your confusion stems from the fact that you're treating addition as a special case. I'd be inclined to parse _infix operators in general_ into some "infix function call" AST element, and use some other (more explicit, and syntax-directed) mechanism to denote whether a function should be inlined. I'm not a compiler guy so take my thoughts with a pinch of salt ;)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson With those changes to the AST, how the operation precedence and associativity are handled?

Comment: @andrybak Isn't precedence/associativity fundamentally a _parsing_ concern? The parser effectively inserts parentheses for you according to what it knows about operator precedence, but _the resulting AST is the same_ as if you'd written the parentheses yourself. (Again, not an expert, someone will probably come and tell me everything I've said is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

LLVM supports [inline attributes](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#function-attributes) e.g.

```
define void @f() alwaysinline { ... }
```

so one option is to treat `+` as a normal function call and let LLVM do its optimization job.

Comment: This would mean that llvm code of every program that uses binary operators will contain several `alwaysinline` functions, which are usually (I assume) inlined on the previous step of compilation.